# Moving latest files from one directory to another

Tags: shell-script, files, find, timestamps

I'm trying to move newest files from one directory to another directory.  The `find` command finds the files but not moving them to another directory.  The destination directory exists.

```
$ cd /app/path1/path2 && \
    find . -type f -printf "%C@ %p\n" | sort | tail -n 2 | \
    cut -d " " -f 2- |xargs -0 mv -t /app/path1/path2/path3

error:  mv: cannot stat No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is due to the fact that you've taken control of the formatting of the output generated by `find`, splitting on newlines now, `\n`. In order to get `xargs` to process your output when using `-0` the output needs to be separated by null characters, `\0`. Here's an easy way to fix it though:

```
$ find . -type f -printf "%C@ %p\n" | sort | tail -n 2 | \
    cut -d " " -f 2- | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 mv -t /app/path1/path2/path3
```

The introduction of the `tr '\n' '\0' command converts the new lines back to nulls.

Comment: @user67186 - great. Please mark this as accepted so other's know your issues been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Either avoid -0 option with xargs, or use -print0. A snippet from the man page for xargs

> In these situations it is
>          better to use the -0 option, which prevents such problems.   When using
>          this option you will **need to ensure** that the program which produces the
>          input for xargs **also uses a null character** as  a  separator.   If  that
>          program is GNU find for example, the **-print0** option does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that your file names won't contain newlines or unprintable characters, then this is one of the rare cases where is makes sense to parse the output of `ls`.

```
cd /app/path1/path2
latest_file=$(LC_ALL=C ls -cr | head -n 1)
mv "$latest_file" /app/path1/path2/path3
```

or if you want to avoid a directory change in the main shell process:

```
latest_file=$(LC_ALL=C ls /app/path1/path2 -cr | head -n 1)
mv "/app/path1/path2/$latest_file" /app/path1/path2/path3
```

Setting `LC_ALL=C` for the run of `ls` ensures that non-ASCII characters are printed literally on many (but not all systems); control characters (which are not printable) are still mangled on many systems.

You can move several files at once. To still cope with most file names, turn off globbing and set `IFS` to split only at newlines.

```
set -f; IFS='
'
mv $(ls -cr /app/path1/path2/* | head -n 2) /app/path1/path2/path3
```

If you can use zsh as your shell, this is a lot easier, since you can sort and select files with a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```
mv /app/path1/path2/*(oc[1,2]) /app/path1/path2/path3
```